# Solving resource dependency in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm new to Terraform and I'm trying to create an AWS SNS topic and subscription. My code looks like the following:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.aws_region}"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic" "sns_my_topic" {
  name = "${var.sns_topic_name}"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "code_commit_notification" {
  depends_on  = ["${aws_sns_topic.sns_my_topic}"]

  topic_arn   = "${aws_sns_topic.sns_my_topic.arn}"
  protocol    = "email"    
  endpoint    = "${var.sns_subscribe_endpoint}"
}
```

However, I get the following error output when running `terraform apply`:

`Error: aws_sns_topic_subscription.code_commit_notification: resource depends on 
 non-existent resource '${aws_sns_topic.sns_my_topic}'`

I was receiving the same error before adding the `depends on` block above as well (and also moved it out of a module after reading https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10462). What is the proper way to get Terraform to process these?

Comment: It should be `depends_on = ["aws_sns_topic.sns_my_topic"]` (without ${} brackets - `depends_on` syntax is a little different from the rest). Still strange that you also get that error when you do not use `depends_on`.

Comment: @fishi probably worth posting that as the answer, especially if you can flesh it out a little.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this looks like a syntax issue.

It should be:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "code_commit_notification" {
  depends_on  = ["aws_sns_topic.sns_my_topic"]

  ...
}
```

The `depends_on` syntax is a little different from the rest and does not require `${}` brackets around the referenced resource variables. It is still a little strange to me that you are receiving the same error without `depends_on`.

Comment: @xyz1234 glad it helped. But you should definitely have a closer look at [ydaetskcoR answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47830945/4478420). It points out possible long-term issues you might have using the `email` protocol type.

Comment: Yep, was just using that as a test parameter and it's not a requirement. However, ydaetskcoR is indeed correct that email is not a supported protocol and that would lead to further errors upon applying.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't spot it at first but `email` is not supported as a protocol for SNS in Terraform because it requires out of band acceptance of the subscription before an ARN is available.

This is mentioned in the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/sns_topic_subscription.html):

> Unsupported protocols include the following:
>
> - email -- delivery of message via SMTP
> - email-json -- delivery of JSON-encoded message via SMTP
>
> These are unsupported because the endpoint needs to be authorized and does not generate an ARN until the target email address has been validated. This breaks the Terraform model and as a result are not currently supported.

The error message you are showing in your question is down to using the wrong syntax as pointed out in [@fishi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47829438/2291321) but your longer term problem will be down to the lack of email SNS subscription support (and likely the cause of a different error before you used the wrong `depends_on` syntax. As an aside, you also definitely don't need the `depends_on` because you have an implicit dependency between the resources that is already created because you refer to the `aws_sns_topic` resource in the `aws_sns_topic_subscription` resource.

When I plan the code in your question without the `depends_on` I get the following error instead which is much clearer:

```
Error: aws_sns_topic_subscription.code_commit_notification: Unsupported protocol (email) for SNS Topic
```